# Getting error trying to use UnityEngine.Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly()

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, integration

I'm using Unity version 5.5.0f3 and getting an error during development. It's showing an error on this line of code:

```
var assembly = Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly(www.bytes);
```

The error message I'm getting:

> `UnityEngine.Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly(byte[])' is obsolete:`This was an internal method which is no longer used'

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly.html), this method is used by the Web Player. However:

> Note that web player is not supported from 5.4.0, so this function no longer serves a purpose and will be deprecated.

If you really want to continue using this method, you can try downloading a prior version of Unity from the [Download Archive](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) - though I would recommend against working on Web Player projects since they will become even more difficult to maintain going forward without official support.